# What would be a connection string for Ironpython to connect to a SQL Server CE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, connection-string, ironpython

I'm working with Visual Studio to connect to an IronPython application to a local .sdf database. However, I get this error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Here's my code:

```
import wpf
import os
import ConfigParser
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System.Data.SqlClient import SqlConnection, SqlParameter
...
conn_string = "Data Source=" + AppData + "local.static.sdf;Password=[PASSWORD];Persist Security Info=True"
connection = SqlConnection(conn_string)
connection.Open()
command = connection.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = 'select nom from employee where id = @id'
command.Parameters.Add(SqlParameter('id', 1))

reader = command.ExecuteReader()
buff = ''
while reader.Read():
    buff = reader['id']
    print buff
connection.Close()
```

Anyone has an idea about what is going wrong with this piece of code?

Thank you!
~Stéphane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting scenario, wonder if you can make it work...

You need

```
 clr.AddReference('System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91')
```

and

```
from System.Data.SqlServerCe import SqlCeConnection, SqlCeParameter
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the initial problem, but I encounter another now:
You are trying to access an older version of a SQL Server Compact Edition database. If this is a SQL Server CE 1.0 or 2.0 database, run upgrade.exe. If this is a SQL Server Compact Edition 3.0 or later database, run Compact / Repair. [ Db version = 4000000,Requested version = 3004180,File name = [PATH]\local.static.sdf ]
I don't understand this error message, could you explain please?

Comment: Thanks, your update solved everything! It was indeed missing the "Version" keyword!